# Serilog with seq cant find System.Net.Http after publish on windows with 4.6.2

Tags: c#, logging, serilog

So I am having trouble getting apps to run after they have gone through a publish process. They work from the visual studios debugger, since a version of System.Net.hhtp is put into the debug directory. I believe that this dll is ngened and stored on client machines, which is why it isn't in the output, what I don't understand is what I am doing wrong.

**:I would like to note that I had no issues setting this up for dotnetcore on linux, and then publishing and running.

Here is a simple cli app I made to show and isolate my issue:

```
using Serilog;
using Serilog.Events;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SerilogTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SetStaticLoggerConfiguration("http://localhost:5341/", @"C:\Logs\IQLRServices\JobDispatcher-{Date}.txt");
            Log.Information("The logger is working.");

        }
        private static void SetStaticLoggerConfiguration(string seqAddress = null, string rollingFileFormat = null)
        {
            LoggerConfiguration logConfig = new LoggerConfiguration();

            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(seqAddress))
            {
                logConfig.WriteTo.Seq(seqAddress, Serilog.Events.LogEventLevel.Verbose, 2500, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
            }
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(rollingFileFormat))
            {
                logConfig.WriteTo.RollingFile(rollingFileFormat,
                        restrictedToMinimumLevel: Serilog.Events.LogEventLevel.Debug,
                        outputTemplate: "{Timestamp:MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff zzz} [{Level}] {Scope} {Properties} {Message} {NewLine}{Exception}");
            }
            if (Environment.UserInteractive)
            {
                logConfig.WriteTo.Console(LogEventLevel.Verbose);
            }

            var log = logConfig.CreateLogger();
            Log.Logger = log;
            Serilog.Debugging.SelfLog.Enable(msg => Log.Error("Serilog internal error: {@ErrorMessage}", msg));
        }
    }
}
```

Here are the Nuget dependencies that I add in order to compile(I added the Serilog.Sinks.Seq package which got its own deps and then added Serilog.Sinks.Console):

```
<packages>
  <package id="Serilog" version="2.5.0" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="Serilog.Formatting.Compact" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="Serilog.Sinks.Console" version="3.0.1" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="Serilog.Sinks.File" version="3.2.0" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="Serilog.Sinks.PeriodicBatching" version="2.1.1" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="Serilog.Sinks.RollingFile" version="3.3.0" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="Serilog.Sinks.Seq" version="3.3.2" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="System.Net.Http" version="4.3.1" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="System.Security.Cryptography.Encoding" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="System.Security.Cryptography.Primitives" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net462" />
</packages>
```

Here is the result of publishing the app with default publish config(This is what happens when I create a installshield setup proj and when I publish directly from vs):

```
Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.Http, Version=4.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
   at SerilogTest.Program.SetStaticLoggerConfiguration(String seqAddress, String rollingFileFormat)
   at SerilogTest.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

Comment: Switched back to log4net for windows.This issue was reproduced on multiple coworkers computers and no fix has been found.

Comment: this seems to be releated to <package id="System.Net.Http" version="4.3.1" targetFramework="net462" />
Actually projects that target framework 4.5+ have a local reference to System.Net.Http located in C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.X\System.Net.Http.dll. 
Result : that lead to conflicts between the nuget package version & the framework version...

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to add the following to your project's `CSPROJ` file:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
  <GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType>true</GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to change anything. I had the first one in there but the second one didn't change anything.